# Need to figure out how to encode an account name on an Opportunity URL hack

Tags: urlhacking

I'm really new to the whole URL hacking thing. I'm trying to create a custom button that will populate a new Opportunity with the associated Account name. Nothing seems to work. The {!Account.ID} merge field works find but no matter what, I can't get the Opportunity Name to populate, and ideally I'd like to populate with the Account Name.

Here's a copy of the URL so far. Any suggestions appreciated.

/006/e?saveURL=%2F006%2Fo&RecordType=012j000000115OM&accid={!Account.Id}&Name=%20test&ent=Opportunity

Answer (score 0):

The value you're looking for is `opp3`. To figure out the correct parameter to use for any field, you can simply right-click it, inspect the element, and observe what its "id" is.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I actually tried opp3 as well using that method (I Googled the bejesus out of this before I posted), but that didn't work either. The URL I tried was 

/006/e?saveURL=%2F006%2Fo&RecordType=012j000000115OM&accid={!Account.Id}&opp3={!Opportunity.Account}&ent=Opportunity


That will bring up the Opportunity Edit page with the record id set and the correct account in the lookup field, but nothing in the Opportunity Name

Comment: @user39015 The problem's your merge field. Where's this button being called from?

Comment: The button is on the Account page, it's trying to create a new Opportunity from there.

Comment: `opp3={!URLENCODE(Account.Name)}` should probably work, then.

Comment: OMG you're the best. If you're ever in Toronto, I owe you a beer. :)